# Stop rendering custom entity label in view mode

Tags: entities

I have declared a custom entity with a schema with a few fields on which is all working as I expect.

I want to remove the label when rendering the entity so have tried the following.

Added some view modes to the entity info hook and although I can see that they exist when I go to manage display none of my entity fields appear. Not sure if this is how it should work or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use https://www.drupal.org/project/eck module?

Comment: No I'm using entity api and a custom entity, I would like to be able to build different view modes in code but I don't think it is possible. I did find a solution see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below function stops a custom entity label from being rendered based on the view mode.

```
function HOOK_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type) {
  if($type == 'YOUR_ENTITY_TYPE' && $build['#entity_view_mode']['view_mode'] == 'YOUR_VIEW_MODE'){
    $build['#page'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```